# Style a HTML select according to the selected option in Angular

Tags: angular, html-select, angular-ngmodel, angular-ngmodelchange

I would like to to style a *select* element in an Angular component differently, when a specific option (with an inactive attribute) is selected.

My component look like this:

```js
class ComponentWithSelect {
  @Input() ngModel: unknown = null;
  @Input() options: { value: unknown, label: string, diasbled: boolean }[]

  inactiveSelected: boolean = false;
  ...

}
```

and the corresponding template look like this:

```html
<select
  [ngModel]="ngModel"
  [class.inactive-select]="inactiveSelected">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options"
    [ngValue]="option.value"
    [disabled]="option.disabled">
    {{option.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

I would like to apply the *inactive-select* class when an option with the inactive attribute is selected OR when a ngModel is passed to the component which corresponds to an option with an inactive attribute.

I tried to use the `(ngModelChange)` to set the **inactiveSelected** property but `$event` parameter passed to a corresponding method (onModelChange) does contain the **value** of the selected option, not the inactive attribute.

I could go with `(change)` and access the *event.target.options.selectedIndex* property **but** neither of those two approaches works, when the *ngModel* is set from outside or its initial value is so, that it corresponds to a option with an inactive property

EDIT:

I tried the suggested approach with using the whole *option* object for **ngValue**

```js
class ComponentWithSelect {

  @Input()
  set ngModel(model: unknown) {
    this.selectedValue = this.options.find(option => option.value === model) || null;
  }
  @Input() options: { value: unknown, label: string, disabled: boolean }[] = [];
  @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter<unknown>();

  selectedValue: { value: unknown, label: string, disabled: boolean } = null;

  onModelChange(option: { value: unknown, label: string, disabled: boolean }) {
    this.ngModel = option.value;
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this.ngModel);
  }
```

and the template

```html
<select
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
  [class.inactive-select]="selectedValue.disabled">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options"
    [ngValue]="option">
    {{option.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

The right option is now selected properly when a corresponding **ngModel** is passed to my component, but when I try to manually change the select, for the for the **first time** nothing is selected, all consequent changes are working fine.

Comment: Instead of `[ngValue]=option.value` try  `[ngValue]=option`. This will pass the whole object to the event.

Comment: If I do this, then the ngModel needs to be an object, but it has to be single property. I mighty work with setter and ngModelChange and use internal selectedValue property instead

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you should notice:

- as Maggini pointed out your ngValue binding is wrong
- use [(ngModel)] instead of [ngModel]

Besides you do not need a secondary boolean property for tracking.
Last note, inital bound object must be one from the options array.

*** .html file ***

```
<select
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
  [ngClass]="{'inactive-select': selectedValue.inactive}"
  >
  <option *ngFor="let option of options"
    [ngValue]="option">
    {{option.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

*** .ts file ***

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  selectedValue: any;

  options: { value: unknown, label: string, inactive: boolean } [] = [
    {
      value: 1,
      label: "1",
      inactive: false,
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      label: "2",
      inactive: true,
    },    
  ]

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedValue = this.options[0];
  }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps also use `<ng-content>` for the options

Comment: Well I need the ngModel/selectedValue to bind the value property, not the whole option object, since it is then used outside to set a property in another object. And the ngModel/selectedValue needs to be set via @Input

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, I had to add getter as well

```js
class ComponentWithSelect {

  @Input()
  set ngModel(model: unknown) {
    this._ngModel = model;
    this.selectedValue = this.options.find(option => option.value === model) || null;
  }
  get (): unknown {
    return this._ngModel;
  }
  @Input() options: { value: unknown, label: string, disabled: boolean }[] = [];
  @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter<unknown>();

  private _ngModel: unknown;
  selectedValue: { value: unknown, label: string, disabled: boolean } = null;

  onModelChange(option: { value: unknown, label: string, disabled: boolean }) {
    this._ngModel = option.value;
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this._ngModel);
  }
```

and the template:

```html
<select
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
  [class.inactive-select]="selectedValue.disabled">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options"
    [ngValue]="option">
    {{option.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```